# Documents in training data belongs to a particular topic in LDA

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, lda

I am working on a problem where I have the Text data with around 10,000 documents. I have create a app where if user enters some random comment , It should display all the similar comments/documents present in the training data.
Exactly like in Stack overflow, if you ask an question it shows all related questions asked earlier.
So if anyone has any suggestions how to do it please answer.

Second I am trying LDA(Latent Dirichlet Allocation) algorithm, where I can get the topic with which my new document belongs to, but how will I get the similar documents from training data. Also how shall I choose the num_topics in LDA.

If anyone has any suggestions of algorithms other than LDA , please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. [Doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) - this is an extension of the extremely popular word2vec algorithm, which maps words to an N-dimensional vector space such that words that occur in close proximity in your document will occur in close proximity in the vector space. U can use pre-trained word embeddings. Learn more on word2vec [here](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/). Doc2vec is an extension of word2vec. This will allow you to map each document to a vector of dimension N. After this, you can use any distance measure to find the most similar documents to an input document.
2. Word Mover's Distance - This is directly suited to your purpose and also uses word embeddings. I have used it in one of my personal projects and had achieved really good results. Find more about it [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)

Also, make sure you apply appropriate text cleaning before applying the algorithms. Steps like case normalization, stopword removal, punctuation removal, etc. It really depends on your dataset. Find out more [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/clean-text-machine-learning-python/)

I hope this was helpful...